# Workflow on Task Modified (using Collect data from user - task form)

Tags: workflow, 2007

I have the requirement to make a workflow fire when a task is modified and after it has been completed.

After the task has been completed, I am trying to set it back to an uncompleted status. From another work flow I update the task 'status' from 'completed' to 'not started'. The status gets updated but after the task is completed the second time the status is not updated from 'not started' to 'completed'.

The reason seems to be because i am unable to update the task's 'outcome' column from 'completed' to '' (blank). Is there a way to update this field non programatically?

Specifically which column in the Task list stores the outcome of the 'Save Draft' or 'Complete Task' button?

Many Thanks,
Nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have more than one status-type field and use them for different purposes.

Comment: Thanks Mike. In my case I'm using Collect data from user which generates a form, which when the user clicks the 'Complete Task' button the task item's 'outcome' column is updated to 'Completed'. Then the workflow won't update that task item's status again... I need to check it because the user could click the 'Save Draft' button...